# iOS to Android studios: TableView to ListView

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, listview

I am creating a cross platform app and having trouble implementing the tableview to a listview.

For the listview, I want each row to be assigned a number (points) and when the user selects a specific row in the listview, it will subtract those points from their total_points and then disable the button...this is if they have enough points

^having trouble doing that in android

I will upload the Swift version and android version (the incomplete one)

iOS:

```
var redeem = ["120 Points", "150 Points", "200 Points", "200 Points", "300 Points", "400 Points", "600 Points"]

var points = [120,150,200,200,300,400,600]
var myIndex = 0

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return(redeem.count)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = redeem[indexPath.row]

    return(cell)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if Total_Points >= points[indexPath.row]
    {
        myIndex = indexPath.row

        Total_Points -= points[indexPath.row]
        pointsLabel.text = "Total Points: \(Total_Points)"

        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController

        self.present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

        save.setValue(Total_Points, forKey: "Total Points")


    }
}
```

Android:

```
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    //define and show in ListView
    String[] redeem = new String[]{

            "120 Points",
            "150 Points",
            "200 Points",
            "200 Points",
            "300 Points",
            "400 Points",
            "600 Points"


    };

    //define a new adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, redeem);

    //assign to listview
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //click listener
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition     = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            // do something
        }
    });
```

Comment: You look on the right path.  What in your android code isn't working yet that you're having trouble with?

Comment: Yeah thank you, but I do not know how to assign a number to each row so that when it is clicked it will subtract from the total_points in android